# Xilinx Virtex II Pro - Determine Number of gates

Tags: fpga

if a FPGA has 30k logic cells, does that mean that it consits of 30k / 2 = 15k logic slices and therefore has 15k / 4 = 3750 programmable logic gates that can perform the AND, OR, NAND ... Operations?

And is there a difference between a logic gate and a configurable logic block (CLB)?

Source: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/33D4F29F1483548586256D740058B428

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You reference the Virtex-II architecture which is quite old, outdated and under obsolescence. For instance, the article you reference date from 2003, 12 years ago; Personally, I haven't touch the Virtex-II in 7 years. So conversation would be quite different if using a recent architecture, i.e. Spartan-6, Virtex-6, or series-7.

It is very hard to compare FPGA utilization to ASIC logic gates. In any case, I recommend running your design into an ASIC synthesizer rather than trusting an FPGA's company marketing comparison data.

A Virtex-II CLB has 2 4-inputs LookUp Table (LUT4), fast-carry logic and 2 registers. It has a little bit more, but this is the significant uses of them.

Each LUT4 can implement any 4-input boolean function, so their usage varies from 2-input gate to 3 2-input gates (for example, 4-input AND). What makes it hard to compare FPGA to ASIC is that FPGA has fixed hardware, so their utilization depends on uses. If you don't use the register associated to a LUT4, it is wasted, thus FPGA designs usually overuse registers since they're "free". Furthermore, the "free" fast-carry logic inflate the slice-to-gate ratio when you use a lot of additions/subtractions.

Finally, remember that a FPGA includes embedded multiplier/accumulator, as well as dual-port RAMs.